# K6 trigger ASP.NET Core server function

Tags: .net-core, signalr, k6

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API project that is using SignalR, I have a hub there which I am connecting to it using k6 (I want to do some load testings) I manage to connect to my hub but I can not figure out how to call a function from my server, my code is

```
import ws from 'k6/ws';
import { check } from 'k6';

export default function () {
    var token = "Bearer userAccessToken";
    const url = 'wss://localhost:5001/session';
    const params = { headers: { "Authorization": token } };

    const res = ws.connect(url, params, function (socket) {
        socket.on('open', () => {
            console.log("opened");
            socket.send(JSON.stringify({ UserId: "aUserId", GameId: "AGameId" }))
        });
        socket.on('close', () => console.log('disconnected'));
    });

    check(res, { 'status is 101': (r) => r && r.status === 101 });
}
```

My function is called `joinGameSession` and it takes two variables the user id and the gameId

```
public async Task<bool> JoinGameSession(JoinGameRequest request)
{
    return true;
}
```

I have managed to trigger functions using Microsoft's SignalR client.

```
const signalR = require("@microsoft/signalr");
require('dotenv').config();

var token = process.env.token ?? "";

var questionIndex = 0;
let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("http://localhost:5000/session", { headers: { "Authorization": token } })
    .withAutomaticReconnect()
    .build();

connection.start().then(() => {
    connection.invoke("JoinGameSession", { UserId: "a", GameId: "x" });
}).catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
})
```

but I can not do it with k6, is there any other tools to achieve my goal?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you check the messages sent by SignalR in your browser's dev console? Your k6 payload is missing the "JoinGameSession" string. The format is probably a little bit different

Comment: what do you mean by "my browser dev console"? in my javascript client I can easily get messages from  signlar and I can call functions too, and ass for the missing "JoinGameSession" I know it is missing, the thing is, where do I add it?

Comment: How is SignalR sending the request? Can you run your JavaScript client in your browser? If you can, you can view the WebSocket messages and mimic their format. If you can't, you need to somehow log the raw messages on the server, intercept your data stream, or read the documentation to find out how those WebSocket messages are supposed to look like.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and [found an old thread](https://community.k6.io/t/bad-handshake-issue-when-using-secure-web-sockets/238/17) which managed to solve it.

```
  ws.connect(wsUrl, function (socket) {
    socket.on('open', () => {
      socket.send('{"protocol":"json","version":1}\x1e') // add this
    });
    socket.on('message', () => console.log('message')); 
    socket.on('close', () => console.log('closed')); 
  });
```

This should allow you to connect to your SignalR hub performing the appropriate handshake. In SignalR, the client and server communicate using a custom protocol. The message being sent in this case is a handshake message that informs the server about the protocol and version the client supports.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i created the connection Id by POST call for negotiate url
http_url=https://server-address/api/hub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1

Then i needed to use this url for my websocket, it depends on how the api have been implemented, but in my case it was:
wss://server-address/api/hub (Notice no need for any connectionId here in url)

```js
import ws from 'k6/ws';
import { check } from 'k6';

export default function () {
    var token = "Bearer userAccessToken";
    const url = 'wss://localhost:5001/session';
    // Token from POST call response with connectionToken
    const params = { headers: { "Authorization": token } };

    const res = ws.connect(url, params, function (socket) {
        socket.on('open', () => {
            // For send call you always need record ASCII '\x1e'
            // This shall be first on opening which is the handshake for signalR
            // protocol and version depends on the implementation but there is 'json' and 'messagepack'
            socket.send('{"protocol":"json","version":1}\x1e')
            console.log("Handshake is done socket is open");
            // For sending base on json check signalR docs:
            // https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/master/specs/HubProtocol.md#invocation-message-encoding
            // type: 1 is Invoke check the docs for more info
            socket.send(`${JSON.stringify({ type:1, target: 'JoinGameSession', arguments: ["aUserId", "AGameId"]})}\x1e`)
        });
        socket.on('message', (message) => console.log(`message: ${message}`)
        socket.on('close', () => console.log('disconnected'));
    });

    check(res, { 'status is 101': (r) => r && r.status === 101 });
}
```